# 2-Way data binding in excel using office.js?

Tags: office-js

I know that it is possible to apply a binding to a worksheet cell and call events on it (ex: data change event). 
I want to know if it is possible to bind the other way, i.e I make the cell value equal to a variable in my code and as the variable value is changed the binded cell value in the sheet must also change (similar to angularjs 2-way binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no 2-way data binding built into the Office add-ins platform, so you’d need to explicitly update the cell value using the office.js APIs.